# can I forward "referrer" information to other address?

Tags: php, referrer

I have two addresses for two servers:

www.urlA.com

www.urlB.com

I have all my websites installed in www.urlB.com, but visitors recognize www.urlA.com primarily.

I have www.urlA.com/index.php as the following

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.urlB.com/');
?>
```

But, when I use this forwarding method, the tracking javascript in www.urlB.com cannot recognize where the visitors are from. I only obtain "NO REFERRING LINK"

What should I do to do the following two jobs:
1. to forward urlA.com to urlB.com
2. to receive the referrer information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a 301 redirect:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.urlB.com/', true, 301);
?>
```

Comment: This works charm!!!

Comment: Then select it as the correct answer! ;)

Comment: Weird, that doesn't seem to make a difference on my test server. In either case, if the redirecting page is accessed via a link, referer data is passed, but if it's accessed directly, no referer data is passed. Whether I use 301 or the default 302 doesn't make a difference.